# How to run a script everytime the X server starts?

Tags: scripts, xorg, startup

I brought one of the 7 inch mini notebooks that have appeared recently (https://www.amazon.co.uk/UDKED-Notebook-MiniHDMI-Connectivity-Terminals/dp/B0C28FFYTK) Its a neat little machine and I have installed Xubuntu 23.04 on it. It has some odd quirks that Im trying to work around, one of them being that the mouse buttons are actually wired up as keyboard keys rather than being part of the mouse device! I have got them working with:

```
xkbset m
xmodmap -e 'keycode 135=Pointer_Button3'
```

I can easily run theses commands once XFCE has started but I need them to run every time the X server starts so I can use the login screen etc. I have put them in a script file and tried running them from:

```
/etc/X11/Xsession.d/
/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
~/.xsession
entries in /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

Unfortunately the script doesnt get run, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can create a `.desktop` file that will call them, make sure you use the full qualified directory name for the commands. Then you can add the `.desktop` file owned by root into the `/etc/xdg/autostart/` directory that gets called before login.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a script before the greeter starts by adding a line in
`/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` under the `[Seat:*]` heading:

```
[Seat:*]
greeter-setup-script=/path/to/script
```

or put it in a file `99-my.conf` in the `lightdm.conf.d` subdirectory.